# Tags for specific software versions

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, version-numbers

What's the policy on tags for specific versions of a piece of software? For example, the [php](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php) tag has the most use, but [php4](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php4) and [php5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php5) are also being used, and there's even [php5.3](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php5.3). Should any of these be synonymed or deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We kind of go back and forth on it, but version numbers do matter in some cases. This does lead to things being tagged multiply when they don't need to be. Witness all the questions tagged:

[tomcat](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tomcat) [tomcat5.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tomcat5.5)

It matters, as I imagine it matters somewhat for things like php.

It's one of those battles where the nuance of where to use a version number and where the Community doesn't think they're needed is hard to express.

Where it falls down is minor point-revs. THAT we don't need.

Comment: So [tag:php5.3] should be killed, but not [tag:php4] and [tag:php5]?

Comment: I'm not a PHP person so can't tell if there is enough different between 5.3 and 5.4 to merit different tags. Generally we don't need it, but there are exceptions.

Comment: It's worth noting that, especially in the case of PHP, that minor points can at times be critical.

Answer (score 0):

There are questions which are very much version dependent and there are questions which apply to all versions. It follows therefore that the tags you referenced should all exist. This is no different to operating system tags. e.g. I may use the generic `windows` tag on one questions and a version specific one elsewhere, depending entirely on context.